# Visibility of assignment to variable in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I recently argued with a friend on a code like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
/**
 * See memory consistency effects in a Java Executor.
 */
public class PrivateFieldInEnclosing {
    private long value;
    PrivateFieldInEnclosing() {}
    void execute() {
        value = initializeValue();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.submit(new Y());
    }

    class Y implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

    private long initializeValue() {
        return 20;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PrivateFieldInEnclosing().execute();
    }
}
```

I argued that it's possible that `value` can be seen as `0` in `Y`, because there's no guarantee that the assignment `value = initializeValue()` is visible in the executor's threads. I said he would need to make `value` a volatile field.

He contradicted me, and said that because it's a private instance field with the value assigned before the thread creation, then the value is visible.

I looked into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4 but I couldn't put my finger on what exactly I can use as backing for my statement. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's irrelevant whether it's private or not. What's relevant is this:

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to submitting a
>   Runnable object to an Executor happen-before its execution begins,
>   perhaps in another thread.

From [Executor docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). Which means that whatever you do before the call to `submit` is visible in the runnable. You could even do it after constructing the executor, and in this particular case it doesn't even matter when the executing thread actually starts because the `submit` method provides a very strong guarantee by itself.

This is one of the features that make java.util.concurrent package very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend would be correct. IF the variable initialization is before a call to `Thread.start` in program order, by JLS 17.4.5 it happens-before the `Thread.start`. The start of the thread also happens-before the first action within the thread. Therefore it also happens-before the call to `doStuffWithValue`.

This particular case cannot be covered by the JLS alone because of the use of `Executor`: you don't know when it calls `Thread.start` for the threads it uses. But from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) you can read that calling `submit` gives you the same guarantee as `Thread.start`: *Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable to an Executor happen-before its execution begins.*

Since happens-before is transitive, the variable initialization happens-before `doStuffWithValue`. The bit about the variable being a private instance field is irrelevant though.

Comment: In this case it isn't even important when the thread actually starts because `submit` guarantees happens-before anyway. So even if your executor implementation uses some sort of crazy thread pools pre-started at JVM startup, you're still safe as long as the executor implementation follows the API spec.

Comment: True, but I'm choosing to defend the argument as presented in the question - that is, from first principles, ignoring the fact that the executor gives more guarantees. Your answer explains the point of view of the executor class well enough.

Comment: @Joni I am not sure. If the thread that runs the `execute()` method does something like `new Thread(new Y()).start()`, then I don't think that `value` is visible in the started `Runnable` without `value` being `volatile`. So, the happens-before guarantees of Executors pointed out by @SergeyTachenov are needed in this case. No?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade which link of the happens-before chain I present in the answer do you doubt? I could be wrong

Comment: @Joni, it appeared from your answer and your comment above that the happens-before edge would be preserved in spite of the use of `executor.submit(new Runnable() {});` and I am not sure we can say that for sure :-).

Comment: Ah no, there are no guarantees of when exactly an executor starts its threads, just like Sergey points out. I'll revise.

Comment: @Kedar, the thread that runs the `execute` method can't possibly do something like `new Y()` because it doesn't even know about the `Y` class. If you meant `new Thread(y).start()`, where `y` is the passed value, then it will still work fine because of the happens-before edge mentioned by Joni. If, on the other hand, it uses some pre-started pooled thread, *then* the guarantees I mention are needed.